# C++ template specialization in shared library - call to specialized function does not work

Tags: c++, templates, shared-libraries

I do have a templated function as well as a specialization thereof in a library
that I want to link to another project. Below a minimial example - the specialization of the template works as expected.

lib.h

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f(T t)
{
    std::cout << "generic template\n";
}
```

lib.cpp

```
#include "lib.h"

template <>
void f(int t)
{
    std::cout << "integer specialization\n";
}

int main()
{
    double d = 3.0;
    int i = 3;

    f(d);
    f(i);
}
```

output

```
generic template
integer specialization
```

In a next step i compile the library into a shared library (commenting the main function)

```
g++ -fPIC -c -o lib.o lib.cpp
g++ -shared lib.o -o libLIB.so
```

main.cpp

```
#include "lib.h"

int main()
{
    double d = 3.0;
    int i = 3;
    f(d);
    f(i);
}
```

compiling main and linking LIB

```
g++ -L . main.cpp -lLIB
```

with lib as a shared library the function specialization does not work as expected,
output:

```
generic template
generic template
```

I know that simply moving the specialized template into the lib.h file resolves the issue.
But I would like to keep the specialization in a seperate .cpp file. Does anyone have an explanation for the described behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there.

You have to remove the generic implementation and add the double, like this:

lib.h

```cpp
template <typename T>
void f(T t);
```

lib.cpp

```cpp
#include "lib.h"
#include <iostream>

template <>
void f(int t)
{
    std::cout << "integer specialization\n";
}

template <>
void f(double t)
{
    std::cout << "double specialization\n";
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "lib.h"
int main()
{
    double d = 3.0;
    int i = 3;
    f(d);
    f(i);
}
```

Compile and run with

```bash
$ g++ -fPIC -shared lib.cpp -o libtest.so
$ g++ -fPIC main.cpp -L. -l test -o main
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
double specialization
integer specialization
```

Alternatively (as you suggested) you can define a generic implementation and let the compiler know that you have a specialization defined elsewhere.

lib.h

```cpp
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void f(T t) {
    std::cout << "Generic implementation\n";
}

template<>
void f( double t );

template<>
void f( int t );
```

lib.cpp

```cpp
#include "lib.h"

template <>
void f(int t)
{
    std::cout << "integer specialization\n";
}

template <>
void f(double t)
{
    std::cout << "double specialization\n";
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include "lib.h"

int main()
{
    double d = 3.0;
    int i = 3;
    float x = 0;
    f(d);
    f(i);
    f("string");
    f(x);
}
```

Compile and run:

```bash
$ g++ -fPIC -shared lib.cpp -o libtest.so
$ g++ -fPIC main.cpp -L. -l test -o main
$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./main
double specialization
integer specialization
Generic implementation
Generic implementation
```

Comment: This really solves my problem. I currently need to provide a specialized version of the function for all required types in my specific application. But in a more general case i would like to have a 'default' implementation in the templated function. Do you have any explanation why the compiler defaults to the template instead of the specialization when i link the library?

Comment: In my understanding, it will try to match the best fit implementation available in the compile unit. If one is found the compiler will use it. However to get your case, you can explicitly say that it is defined elsewhere. I will update the answer.

Comment: Specifying the specialized functions in lib.h works - thanks!